# Trying to use $lookup to retrieve data from two collections of same database

Tags: mongodb-query

I am trying to retrieve data from two collections posts and users with userId and ObjectId(_id) respectively as joining condition using $lookup. But it just returns me data from collection posts along with an empty array. Here is my query.

```
db.posts.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'users',
        localField: 'userId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'user_data'
    }
}]).pretty();
```

Comment: Please use [code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) to format your code.

Comment: Your query looks correct. Ensure you have matching records in Users collection.